# How to route to sub directories / folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, view, subdirectory

In Rails, how can I place views in sub directories / sub folders (just to organize them), and still have them properly routed/rendered?

---

I want to organize some of my views under the namespace of another view. All views are under one controller.

I want

`www.custom.com/controller/action/`

to show the `action.html` view.

I want to use this url

`www.custom.com/controller/action/sub_action`

instead of

`www.custom.com/controller/sub_action`

Both are sibling actions and views under the same `controller`.
I wish for `action` to render a page, and also be used as a namespace for other views.

I don't want/need to make another controller or resource.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render in your controller, you can specify which view you want (if it's not in the conventional place for any reason).

```
render 'controller/action/sub_action'
```

or even:

```
render 'some_other_controller/action/sub_action'
```

Checkout the [Rails guides on rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Comment: How about for routing?

Comment: You can set up a member route, or non-resourceful route to direct requests for any URL to any controller's action. Check out the `Routing From the Outside in` guide in the Rails documentation.

Comment: something along the lines of: `get 'controller/action/sub_action', to: 'controller#sub_action'` should do the trick (though beware of the order in the routes.rb file if your new route overlaps with any existing routes, like `controller/action/:id`)

Comment: `get 'controller/action/sub_action'` specifies the url, not the folder path. since I am not using conventional location for `subaction` views, I need to specify this. I've tested that I cannot just put a view under a subfolder of the views folder. What would be the optional hash key-value pair to specify a view file that is in a subfolder of the views folder? I haven't been able to find any resource for this, including the `Routing from the Outside in` guide.

I believe the rendering solution may be promising. I'll look into it.

Comment: i believe all the renders result in partials. which doesn't produce a new url.

Comment: The route is nothing to do with the folder path. You've said you want a non-standard URL (for which you need the route) *and* a non-standard file location for the view (for which you need to render specifically in the controller action - sub_action, for you) - the fact that the folder path *looks* like the URL path; that's just happenstance.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem is, where do I put the render command? It should be within an action of the controller. If I have an action called `sub_action`, and I put `render 'some_other_controller/action/sub_action'` in it, then rails will still require a view file named `sub_action` that is NOT in a subfolder. Duplicating view files, with one being empty, and the one in the subfolder with actual content seems silly. This, combined with the fact that `render` doesn't load a different page, but rather, injects a partial into the current page.

Comment: Have you tried? I am fairly sure, that if you call render from the controller, you can specify the view, and it can be in any folder you like.

Comment: yes i've tried. you're not even listening/reading to my question anymore.

" The problem is, where do I put the render command? It should be within an action of the controller. If I have an action called sub_action, and I put render 'some_other_controller/action/sub_action' in it, then rails will still require a view file named sub_action that is NOT in a subfolder. Duplicating view files, with one being empty, and the one in the subfolder with actual content seems silly."